# Linked batch file in MS Excel - how to stop security warning?

Tags: excel

We have a very complex spreadsheet that has a ton of links pointing to other spreadsheets on our fileserver, and have had a problem with new workbooks becoming corrupted when opened in the same instance as our "master" spreadsheet. We have replaced the links to excel files with links to batch files that open excel file with the /x switch to start the linked workbook in a new instance of Excel, and this has seemed to solve the problem, *however*, we get a security warning each time we click the link to the batch file, and cannot find an option anywhere in trust center to turn this off. No code here, not really applicable, more an options question. Excel 365.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option:

Opening a file through CMD can be achieved through vba using Wscript.Shell this means that you don't need to access the bat files and can use the locations within cells of your master spreadsheet:

```
Sub OpenWorkbook()

        ' variable for the creation of the object: wscript.shell
    Dim objShell

        ' set the("Wscript.Shell") to the variable objShell 
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

        ' Open Workbook where the file and filepath is in cell A1 = c:\temp\test.xlsx
    objShell.Run ("""" & Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1") & """")

        ' release objectshell
    Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Alternatively you can have the contents of your bat files within the cells but amend the script to remove the quotation marks.